# HTML Elements are same height yet one is visually bigger that the other

Tags: html, css

The "login the enter chat" button is supposed to fit inside the messageBox div, but is (visually) way bigger than messageBox. I even made padding and margin 0 but it did not change anything.

What is the culprit here (besides myself)?

```css
#chatbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#loginContainer {
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#loginContainer input {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input#login {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: none;
    color: blue;
    border: none;
}

#loginForm {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#messagesArea {
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

#messageBox {
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 1px 1px;
}

#messageForm {
    display: none;
}

#messageBoxBlocked {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Chat with Customer Service</h1>
        <div id="chatbox">
            <div id="loginContainer">
                <form id='loginForm'>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username"/>
                    <input id="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
                </form>
    
            </div>
            <div id="messagesArea">
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p> 
            </div>
            <div id="messageBox">
                <button id="messageBoxBlocked">Log in to enter chat</button>
                <form id="messageForm">
                    <textarea name="messageBox" placeholder="Enter a message"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="Send"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `p` element inside your `#messagesArea` has a margin values.
2. The `#messagesArea` has padding.

Remove these two and you are done :)

```
#messagesArea {
    padding: 0;
}

#messagesArea p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
#chatbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#loginContainer {
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#loginContainer input {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input#login {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: none;
    color: blue;
    border: none;
}

#loginForm {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#messagesArea {
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
}

#messagesArea p {
  margin: 0;
}
#messageBox {
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 1px 1px;
}

#messageForm {
    display: none;
}

#messageBoxBlocked {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Chat with Customer Service</h1>
        <div id="chatbox">
            <div id="loginContainer">
                <form id='loginForm'>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username"/>
                    <input id="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
                </form>
    
            </div>
            <div id="messagesArea">
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p> 
            </div>
            <div id="messageBox">
                <button id="messageBoxBlocked">Log in to enter chat</button>
                <form id="messageForm">
                    <textarea name="messageBox" placeholder="Enter a message"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="Send"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Note - if you do need these margin/padding values - make sure you set the container (`#chatbox`) with the correct `height` value. In your case - it should be `512px` - it will include the padding of the `#messageArea` and the border of the `#messageBox`).

Comment: thanks! How is the margin from the `p` able to spilling over the div?

Comment: The margin-top of the `p` element makes the element above it consum more height.

Comment: Ah. I am hoping you could shed some more light for me.. I thought that if you have padding and margin, it would just increase the size of the parent container, no? Shouldn't the "messagesArea" just increase in total width (i.e. I set it to 350, then adding 10px for padding for a total of 360px) and not affect "messageBox"?

Comment: There are also other things that might affect the general flow here, like floating/block/inline/inline-block elements and so on. What you see here is called margin collapsing.

Comment: Well i've accepted your answer since you definitely fix the problem.. but if you're able to expand more I will appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: I think the best place to learn about this is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing :)